# Move all Bootstrap .clearfix according to prepended div and layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, template

I am using the Bootstrap class `.clearfix` after every second(or third) `<div>` to keep each row starting at the same height on all screen sizes even if two divs on same row have different height.

I use a hidden `<div>` at the top as template for information I will get from an  ajax call. I have simulated this event in the demo with a button to click and content "insert N" for simplicity. The counter is only there for the demo. In this snippet I also added `<br />` to some news to simulate difference in height.

When I insert a `<div>` at the top with jquery, I need the `.clearfix` classes to move accordingly to keep the current layout, and add a `.clearfix` if there are too many `<div>` after the last `.clearfix`.

The layouts are 1 field on top row, and 2(or 3) fields on all other rows on screen 992px and up, if smaller screen just 1 field per row.
(Just to be clear, when I talk about "row", I do not mean the bootstrap class `.row`)

I have managed to get this working with jquery `.clone()` / `.prepend()` / `.each()` / `.prev()` / `.next()` / `.insertAfter()` / `.nextUntil()` / `.nextAll()`, but I cant shake the feeling that it is extremely long-winded and hard for next generation coders to maintain. **Can anyone offer a cleaner method?**

```js
// simulate new content from ajax call
$('#clickit').on('click', function(){
  // demo counter
  var counter = (parseInt($('#output').text())+1);
  $('#output').text(counter); // view

  // clone template before filling up with info
  var template = $('.modalInputHolder_679');
  var templateClone = template.clone();
  
  // remove template-class from old template
  // insert new content in new div(old template) and new template
  template.removeClass('modalInputHolder_679').text('insert  '+counter);
  templateClone.text('hidden');
  $(".row").prepend(templateClone);
  
  // move clearfix divs up one place
  var replaceClass;
  var clearfix = $(".row .clearfix");
  clearfix.each(function(index){
    var that = $(this);
    var prev = that.prev();
    if(index==0) { // if first .clearfix
     replaceClass = that.next().attr('class'); // get new class for old template
     prev.attr('class',replaceClass);
    }
    prev.insertAfter(that); // move up
  });
  
  // accomodate for both 1-2 layout and 1-3 layout(wide first, rest split among 2/3 cols)
  var clearfixLength = clearfix.length;
  if(clearfixLength>1){ // if more than two .clearfix
    // find number of divs between clearfixes
    var type = clearfix.eq(0).nextUntil('.clearfix').length;
    var last = clearfix.eq((clearfixLength-1)); // get last .clearfix
    // get number of divs after last
    var trailingFields = last.nextAll();
    var trailingLength = trailingFields.length;
    if(trailingLength>type){ // if difference is more than filled up (2 or 3)
      var clearfixClone = clearfix.eq((type-1)).clone(); // create clone of clearfix
      trailingFields.eq((type-1)).after(clearfixClone); // input new clearfix
    }    
  }
});
```

```css
.fullWidthColumn { background-color: #FF0000!important; }
.row>.col-xs-12:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #00FF00; }
.row>.col-xs-12:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #0000FF; }
.modalInputHolder_679 { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button class="btn btn-default" id="clickit">Insert news</button> <span> Counter: </span><span id="output">0</span><br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 fullWidthColumn modalInputHolder_679">hidden</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 fullWidthColumn">first</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">second<br />...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">third</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">fourth</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">fifth<br />...</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">sixth<br />...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">seventh</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's jsfiddles of both 2 col layout ([code](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/35p1h8hz/)/[view](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/35p1h8hz/show/)) and 3 col layout ([code](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/vtmf6tjt/)/[view](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/vtmf6tjt/show/)), they use the same javascript and css, but slightly different html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Define counter

I'd define a counter like this:

```
var counter = 0; //I'd define it in upper scope 
$('#clickit').on('click', function () {
    counter++;
    $('#output').text(counter);
```

#### Define template:

You defined a template in html, and access and clone it like this:

```
var template = $('.modalInputHolder_679');
var templateClone = template.clone();

template.removeClass('modalInputHolder_679').text('insert  '+counter);
templateClone.text('hidden');
$(".row").prepend(templateClone);
```

It's verbose. I'd define it like this:

```
var $row = $('<div class="col-xs-12 fullWidthColumn"></div>')
    .text('insert   ' + counter);
$(".row").prepend($row);
```

Since the template is short, you can just define it in js code. If the real template is long, you can define it at somewhere else to avoid handling `modalInputHolder_679` things (use the class name on its wrapper).

#### Type?

```
var type = clearfix.eq(0).nextUntil('.clearfix').length;
```

Maybe `colCnt` is better. And the `.eq(0)` can be replaced with `.first()`. Similarly, `.eq((clearfixLength - 1));` can be replaced with `.last()`.

So this section can be change to:

```
var last = clearfix.last(); // get last .clearfix
var colCnt = last.prevUntil('.clearfix').length;
```

#### Better access

Since you do `insertAfter` on every clearfix, why not just insert them again?

```js
var counter = 0; //I'd define it in upper scope 
var clearfixTemplate = $('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
var rowTemplate = $('<div class="col-xs-12 fullWidthColumn"></div>');
var rowWrapper = $(".row");
$('#clickit').on('click', function () {
    counter++;
    $('#output').text(counter);

    var clearfix = rowWrapper.find(">.clearfix");
    var sections = rowWrapper.find(">.col-xs-12"); //you may need a class name to indicate the `information` element

    sections.eq(0).attr("class", sections.eq(1).attr("class"));

    if (clearfix.length < 2)
        return;

    var last = clearfix.last();
    var colCnt = last.prevUntil('.clearfix').length;

    sections.each(function (index) {
        if (index % colCnt === colCnt - 1) {   
            var clear = clearfix[Math.floor(index / colCnt)]; //reuse them
            if (!clear) { //if not enough
                clear = clearfixTemplate.clone();
            }
            $(this).after(clear);
        }
    });

    var row = rowTemplate.clone()
        .text('insert   ' + counter);
    rowWrapper.prepend(row);

});
```

```css
.fullWidthColumn {
  background-color: #FF0000!important;
}

.row>.col-xs-12:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

.row>.col-xs-12:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #0000FF;
}

.modalInputHolder_679 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button class="btn btn-default" id="clickit">Insert news</button> <span> Counter: </span><span id="output">0</span><br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 fullWidthColumn">first</div>    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">second<br />...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">third</div>   
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">fourth</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">fifth<br />...</div>   
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">sixth<br />...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">seventh</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and for taking the time to look at it! :) However I can't accept it as the correct answer(yet?) because it does not work as intended anymore. I will make use of some of it, but your full code does not work on large screens. Error1; .col-md-6 / col-md-4 are ignored in your solution. Error2; .clearfix are added but not moved up. Error3; .clearfix are added at the bottom one step too soon. Error4; template is no longer hidden. I have been trying to debug it, but as it created more bugs than solutions, I cant accept this answer. Sorry, and thanks for good ideas

Comment: @turbopipp  Well.. 1: I can't find col-md-4 in your code. 2: It does, please  inspect the result, don't just read the code. 4: the template is not in the document at all. Don't just copy my code to your project, I also changed your html.

Comment: @turbopipp You need `rel="stylesheet"` in your html snippet.

Comment: @turbopipp It seems that I focused on your **stackoverflow snippet** and ingored your jsfiddle. I'm sorry for this.

Comment: You are right when it comes to 2 and 4, and 3 doesn't really matter. :) The error was me trying to implement templateID again because the ajax calls could return information to multiple newsfields with different layout, and I had to identify the correct template inside the scope. But you had no way of knowing that was a requirement, so that's on me. :) Thanks for your help, ofc I will accept your answer now. :)

Comment: Wish this answer can help you :D  @turbopipp